# Merging Two Datasets, Removing recurring columns, Adding a new column

Tags: r, dataset

I have two datasets :
[Here's the 1st](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikio3dexmvtg2w6/J_B5H1.csv), and [Here's the 2nd](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pcrtz0o7lka8u8p/J_BL5H1.csv).

My aim is to merge these datas, removing the 1st or 2nd "JN" column since it's recurring, and find the ratio of "Freq" between these datas.

For each Row, I want to use this calculation :

```
=(100)-(100*(FreqBL/FreqB))
```

and place this new calculation to 4th column.

The new data should look like:

```
JN  FreqBL  FreqB  Success Ratio
 4    10      33      69.6969
```

But I don't know how to select all rows seperately and the necessary code for the calculation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to `merge` the data sets. For the next time, I will recommend you provide a small reproducible example.

```
> new.dt <- merge(dt1, dt2)
> new.dt$"Success ratio" <- with(new.dt, 100-(100 * (FreqBL/FreqB)))
> head(new.dt)
  JN FreqB FreqBL Success ratio
1  4    33     10      69.69697
2  8    49     10      79.59184
3 10    44     13      70.45455
4 11    38      7      81.57895
5 13    29      3      89.65517
6 17    15     10      33.33333
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, since I'm just a beginner, I'm trying to learn as fast as possible.

Comment: @forochelian here's a page that might help you get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example